# Where is the icon for Mounted Drives Stored?

Tags: icons, themes, gnome-shell, icon-themes

I can't seem to find the location of the icon for mounted drives anywhere -

[image]

I already tried the following paths -

```
/usr/share/icons/ 
~/.local/share/icons/
/usr/share/pixmaps/
~/.icons/
```

Where does GNOME store it? Thanks

Comment: what is your Ubuntu Version and the icon in your question is from which icon theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the icon theme you are using.

Following example is for Ubuntu 18.10 hard disk drive mounting.

Please note that the path for different types of mountings for example HDD Drive mounting, SSD Drive mounting, USB Drive mounting, External Drives may vary slightly.

When the icon theme is LoginIcons, it is located at - 
`/usr/share/icons/LoginIcons/apps/48/drive-harddisk.svg`

[image]

Humanity theme - 
`/usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/48/drive-harddisk.svg`

[image]

Yaru theme - 
`/usr/share/icons/Yaru/48x48/devices/drive-harddisk.png`

[image]